# How do I retain the "name" attribute of an input in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How do I retain the "name" attribute of an input in an ASP.NET application?

I just went through how to retain the IDs, but unfortunately, the jquery validation plugin using the name attribute--hence I'm trying to retain the name.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

```
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" runat="server" /><br />

<label>Email</label>
<input type="text" email name="email" runat="server" /><br />

<label>Password</label>
<input type="text" password id="password" name="password"  runat="server" /><br />

<label>Verify Password</label>
<input type="text" verify id="verify" name="verify"  runat="server" /><br />

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="submit" Text="Submit" />
```

Comes out as:

```
<label>Name</label>

<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderBody$ctl00" type="text" /><br />



<label>Email</label>

<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderBody$ctl01" type="text" email="" /><br />



<label>Password</label>

<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderBody$password" type="text" id="password" password="" /><br />



<label>Verify Password</label>

<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderBody$verify" type="text" id="verify" verify="" /><br />



<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderBody$submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
```

Comment: Give a sample html code of your asp.net page

Comment: you tried $('.class_element').attr('name')

Comment: See this post also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740367/html-name-attribute-generated-for-asp-net-child-controls-instead-of-the-uniqu

Answer (score 1):

Use UniqueID property for getting names. If you want to get the name of email field, use like this `<%=email.UniqueID%>` inside the jquery for getting names `<%=email.ClientID%>` will yield the ID of the control

Comment: That's probably the best way to do it. Unfortunately, the jQuery doesn't like the name with the "$" in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 4.0 you could try setting `ClientIDMode` to `Static`. Other than that, I would suggest referencing the control by the `ClientID` (ID) or the `UniqueID` (Name) in jQuery:

```
var el = $("#<%=TextBox1.UniqueID%>");
if (el){
    var value = el.val();
}
```