# How can I get the textbox value based on the name in controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Do any one know how can I get the textbox value based on the name in controller?

Example:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="stDate" Text='<%# Eval("StartDate")%>' Width="6em" />
```

When I read from the source code, it's show as below:

```
<input name="ctl00$cplh$GridView1$ctl10$stDate" type="text" id="stDate" style="width:6em;" />
```

How can I get the get this textbox value based on the name `ctl00$cplh$GridView1$ctl10$stDate` in the controller?

NOTE: the reason I would like to do in this way is because I have more then 1 textbox are using the same ID (stDate)

Comment: why not write the name property directly instead of looking at generated one

Comment: RE `NOTE`: is this even possible? I was under the impression that each element, whether regular HTML or ASP.NET, had to have a unique `ID`. Kind of the purpose of calling it an _ID_, it _identifies_ the element.

Comment: It's possible but doesn't follow conventions of XHTML, and goes against best practices. all and all it shouldn't be done.

Answer (score 0):

To get the ID generated on the page, you have to get the ClientID

```
stDate.ClientID
```

Answer (score 0):

there's a few things I want to suggest:

- ID's must be unique, you should assign an unique identifier to each controller in your page.
- .NET needs a hook to your control - so it needs to set the name if it is going to be created by .NET (you can't change it even if you try to force it).
- If you want to assign a common name between controllers use the attribute class, for example:
  `<input id="txtbox1" class="commonController" type="text" value="input1">
  <input id="txtbox2" class="commonController borderClass" type="text" value="input2">`

*p.d.: remember, you can assign multiple classes to a controller.*

- Also remember that `id` is only for client side DOM manipulation... `name` is required for the browser to actually post the content

If you want more info check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470268/html-input-name-vs-id) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740367/html-name-attribute-generated-for-asp-net-child-controls-instead-of-the-uniqu)

Answer (score 0):

If you using ASP.NET 4 you can you set the ClientIDMode to static on the textbox then asp keeps the id as you had set it.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="stdate" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

This helps if you need to use the textbox in client side scripting. [Here's](http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx) an article on it. You would need to make sure that the id is unique then, if you need a common name it would be better to use a class as Luis suggested.